# Angular reference an NgModel passed in

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-forms, ngmodel

In the HTML template of one component:

```
<input [(ngModel)]='dataModel' #data="ngModel" />
<app-my-component [model]='data'></app-my-component>
```

In `app-my-component`:

```
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() model: NgModel;
}
```

At runtime, it gives me an error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: null'. Current value: 'model: address'`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why are you doing this, simply do:

```
<input [(ngModel)]='dataModel'/>
<app-my-component [model]='dataModel'></app-my-component>
```

ts:

```
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() model: string;
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to reference the `invalid` and `errors` property of the `inpput`.

Comment: in this case you should send error and invalid like model to your app-my-... something like:
```@Input('valid') valid: string;
@Input('errorText') error: string;```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`ChangeDetectorRef`** to tell angular that there are new changes to the data  of NgModel.

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: This might work but does not suit my needs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is your need then